# meson can't build systemd from source: "getent" not found

Tags: yocto, systemd, bitbake, meson-build

I'm compiling `systemd` version 237 from source in a cross compiling environment (yocto `sumo`).

By the bitbake recipe, systemd is built by meson.

I upgraded meson version to 0.49.2 (copied from `warrior`) since my other recipes require that version.

when I do `bitbake systemd`, I have this error:

> meson.build:678:0: ERROR:  Program or command 'getent' not found or not executable

I opened `meson.build` and it has:

```
getent_result = run_command('getent', 'passwd', '65534')
if getent_result.returncode() == 0
    ...
endif
```

I searched a little bit, it seems that `getent` is a standard command, and in my building host (Ubuntu 16), I can run:

```
getent --version
```

> getent (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11.2) 2.23

So `getent` does exist, at least in my host Ubuntu.

Then how to fix the mison issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think your toolchain is missing `glibc-utils`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it from the host with:

```
HOSTTOOLS += "getent"
```

however OE-Core doesn't have that as standard and systemd builds see to work ok so I'm a little puzzled why you're hitting the requirement.